# SPSS creating table with multipe variables down, and the variables values horizontally

Tags: spss

Let's say I have two variables. "Like Ice" and "Like cofee".
Both variables have the same values "Do not like", "like", "love".

I want to make a table displaying this:

```
        | Do not like | Like | Love |
Like ice|     8       |   3  |  15  |
Like Cof|    13       |   7  |   6  |
```

the variables downwards, and their values horizontal, displaying the number of choices.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `CTABLES`? (I do not - but I'm pretty sure this would be much easier with them) One way to do it without `CTABLES` would be to use `VARSTOCASES` to put ice and cof in the same column and then use `CROSSTABS`.

Comment: Thank you, Custom tables worked . I did not manage this earlier because I did not know I should put "Category Position" to "Row Labels in Columns" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy with ctables.  Put the variables in the rows and specify statistic in the opposite dimension.  This is called a comperimeter table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A more detailed explanation:
   - Analyze ->  tables -> custom tables
   - Drag variables into rows (stacked, above eachother)
   - Set "category position" to "Row Labels in Columns".
   (make sure variables are nominal)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only original `TABLES` module, or for some other reason want to stick with it, you may use the following syntax:

```
TABLES
   /TABLE var1+var2 by (LABELS).
```

Default statistics is `COUNT`.